# Typo3 11.5: paginator.paginatedItems containing ALL items instead of items for current page

Tags: pagination, typo3

I'm using extension numbered_pagination to replace pagination widget.
Allmost everything works fine, but all the items are displayed on every page.

```
$itemsPerPage = 20;
$paginator = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Pagination\QueryResultPaginator($allItems, $currentPage, $itemsPerPage);
```

```
<f:for each="{paginator.paginatedItems}" as="item" iteration="iterator">
```

The pagination is ok (i.e. correct number of links/pages), but instead of 20 items all the items are displayed on every page.

Thanks for any hint!
Anna

Comment: with items you mean the records you want to paginate or the pages? are you using the class of the numberedpagination? in your own extension you need to switch the used pagination implementation

Comment: Yes, I mean the records.    

Actually I simply copied it from [link]https://github.com/georgringer/numbered_pagination, chapter "Usage".  


I expected `$paginator = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Pagination\QueryResultPaginator($allItems, $currentPage, $itemsPerPage);`  to do the "slicing".  

What do you mean by "you need to switch the used pagination implementation"?

Comment: code like this:
 $pagination = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(NumberedPagination::class, $paginator, $maximumNumberOfLinks);

the parts of your code looks ok but without seeing everything it is hard to help, is it maybe available at github?

Comment: Hi Georg, thanks for your help!  
[link]https://github.com/annaemde/tfm_plan  

See DownloadController.php, listAction(), end of function, and Templates/Download/List.html, end of template. Context: Users can download files, the downloads are written into a protocol which can be listed on this page.
----
As far as I understand, PAGINATION is the set of links to the different pages – this works fine.

Comment: My problem is: I expect {paginator.paginatedItems} to show only those 20 items (=downloads) on page 1, 2, 3 etc., but it always contains all the items. Thus I don't understand where the set of all items is sliced into pieces of 20 items each.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is the following. The pagination does **not** work when using

```php
$query->statement($sql);
```

There are 3 options I see:

- Rebuild the query using the `query` object and not by building a plain SQL
- Keep the query but make an array out of it and use the `ArrayPaginator`
- Build the query with plain sql just retrieve a list of UIDs and use that in a 2nd regular query.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at this! I just added a function "findItemsOnCurrentPage()" to my repository that uses "LIMIT X,Y". I prefer simple SQL as I am so used to it from database development :-)  But I will try option 1 as it is "best practice".